# How to replace keyboard hotkeys

Tags: keyboard, autohotkey, hotkeys

windows: I would like to press CTRL+Z and let the computer understand (the OS) that I pressed CTR+SHIFT+2.

So how can I reconfigure hotkeys, or replaces hotkeys?

Answer (score 1):

Once you get AutoHotkey installed...

```
#IfWinActive        ; Use globally for all programs
^z::SendInput ^+2   ; Replace Control+Z with Control+Shift+2
```

AutoHotkey will override 'standard' program commands except in the case of OS-specific items such as Win+(whatever) commands.

Answer (score 0):

That specific combination will not work because CTRL-Z is a standard command already that stands for Undo.

There are some commands that you cannot remap.

Comment: I am looking for any convenient way to replace CTRL SHIFT 2 with other input, maybe pressing space 2 times?

Comment: Hotkey commands typically require some combination beginning with CTRL, or ALT, or SHIFT. While it is possible that you could use a third-party program that would watch for and convert a double-tap spacebar as CTRL-SHIFT-2, this would also run into other applications which interpret SPACE-SPACE as something else.

Comment: it will work for me, can you please refer me to such program or google keyword?

Comment: No. Product recommendations are off topic here on SuperUser because products change and answers regarding them will change, and therefore they are not a good fit here. Also, the only program I'm familiar with that offers this capability is already tagged in your original post.

Comment: got ya autohotkey